# Need help with SQL query in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a table with the following columns

```
member_number
step_count 
social_activity -- (which contains both Challenges and Posts)
high_fives
```

Basically all the columns 2-4 are counts for members.

I want to create a report where I can display `member_number`, `step_count`, `social_activity` (where it is 'challenges'), `social_activity` (where it is 'posts') and `high_fives`.

I wrote the query

```
select member_number, step_count, social_activity
from ABC
group by member_number
```

But I want the query to get the separate count for `social_activity` ('challenges') and social_activity ('posts').

Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need a *conditional sum* based on CASE:

```
select member_number,
   sum(case when social_activity = 'challenges' then step_count else 0 end) as challenges,
   sum(case when social_activity = 'posts' then step_count else 0 end) as posts
from ABC
group by member_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify if you want to count the number of rows in the step_count or summing it. I've assumed that it contains a previously calculated count and thus I've used the SUM function. It would work the same with a count() instead a sum(). If you need to add the high_fives as a general total (at member level, instead of at activity type level, you need to do an outer query. Try this. This will not work in SQL Fiddle as MySQL does not support full outer joins, but it should work in Teradata.

```
select a.member_number, sum(challenges), sum(posts), sum(high_fives) from (
select a.member_number, Challenges, Posts from
(select member_number, sum(step_count) as Challenges from activity where social_activity ='Challenge' group by member_number) a 
full outer join 
(select member_number, sum(step_count) as Posts from activity where social_activity ='Post' group by member_number) b on a.member_number =  b.member_number group by a.member_number
 ) a inner join activity b on a.member_number = b.member_number
group by a.member_number
```